# Can't correctly compare two text files using 'cmp'

Tags: files, text

I am trying to compare two text files using:

```
if cmp -s file1 file2
 then
echo "Accepted"
 else
echo "Wrong Answer"
fi
```

A C++ program's output is pipelined to file1, and the expected output is already saved by me in file2. For instance, a 'Hello World' program prints the output to file1, and I had already copied the 'Hello World' text in file2. In spite of the text in the two files being exactly the same, why am I getting 'Wrong Answer' ?

Whereas this works when I print integers from 1 to 10 to file1 and already save the expected output in file2. This time, I am getting "Accepted" . 
What I can infer is that number comparison works fine whereas character comparison doesn't work.

Comment: That works for me. Try `if $(cmp -s file1 file2)`

Comment: @KasiyA That doesn't work.

Comment: Try to copy the c++ program's output to file2 and compare again

Comment: Because in C++ program's output the end of line character is `\0` but in regular text it's `\n` or `\r\n`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.

That probably seems to be the cause of the problem. But I tried adding a "\n" at the end of the C++ program, but still its being shown as unequal. 
Do you have a workaround, will 'diff' work any different ? (But I wouldn't want to use it because it doesn't have the -s option).

Comment: Nono. when you add `\n` at the end of c++ output, it already will print `\n\0` and it doesn't work again. Can I have your c++ program's output? **if the file is private you can replace them with example words instead** I only want to know what is the end of line char there.

Comment: No, there's nothing private,let me just share it in a minute.

Comment: I am sorry that took longer than expected. Here's the code, it has the script, a c++ program, an input file (in case the input is to be read from the input file), an output file (the output of the C++ program) and another 'res_op_file' which contains the expected output. I am comparing 'op_file' with 'res_op_file'. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1JVf_4oH8L1WExNWG1rRHo2NGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I am basically trying to get a setup to check the programs by using test-cases automatically.Kind of a online-judge for my college assignments.This setup is to check the program generated output and ideal outputs and check whether the program gives correct output or not.

Can you suggest me what framework or 'stuff' (because I don't know what exactly I have to use) to connect a PHP made web interface to the bash-based structure of the system.

Comment: :( I couldn't open your file. please post the prog.cpp and op_file and res_op_file on http://paste.ubuntu.com/ instead and post its link.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9747578/ <-- CPP 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/9747584/ <--op_file
http://paste.ubuntu.com/9747601/ <-- res_op_file

Comment: You were right @KasiyA , it was about the trailing /0 , and nerd65536's solution fixed it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `cmp` without the `-s` option, it'll explain *why* it thinks the files are different.

From your code posted in your comments, Here's what your files look like with a hex editor:

`res_op_file` is 12 bytes long and ends with a `\n` (`0a`):

```
0000000: 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 640a            Hello World.
```

`op_file` is 11 bytes long and doesn't have the `\n`:

```
0000000: 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 64              Hello World
```

`diff` has the `-Z` option, "--ignore-trailing-space" which will ignore any whitespace at the end of a line. If you don't care about `diff`'s output, just put `> /dev/null` to the end of the command, like:

```
if diff -Z file1 file2 > /dev/null
 then
echo "Accepted"
 else
echo "Wrong Answer"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,your solution worked perfectly. Initially I was using diff, but later I read on Stack Overflow that cmp is faster as it stops comparison at the very first occurrence of a mismatch.But I'll stick to 'diff' now.

Comment: Ah, In that case you may also want to add the `-q` option on diff, which does the same thing.